# How to set minimum size of container in fxml

Tags: resize, fxml

Im trying to work with javafx and i've created a fxml for my interface.

But now, i have a problem with the size of my pane.

```
<VBox minHeight="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
```

For example in my VBox and their childrens i specify a minHeight. But while the application is running, i can make my box smaller than 200p and i dont understand why. How do i correctly set a minimal height or witdh?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimal size will work as expected for everything in JavaFX *except* when you have a resizable Pane as the root of a scene (which is probably your case).

Where you want to make the root not get smaller based on a minimum size as an enclosing stage is resized, you can try one of the following approaches:

**A. Set a minimum size for the Stage**

```
stage.setMinWidth(200);
stage.setMinHeight(200);
```

You can adjust the minimum height and width values by the size of the decorations for the stage if necessary.

OR

**B. Define a ScrollPane as the root of your Scene**

```
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(content);
scrollPane.setMinViewportWidth(200);
scrollPane.setMinViewportHeight(200);
Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane);
```

*Aside:*

It could be argued that the behavior of not enforcing stage minimum size based upon the minimum size of the scene root is "wrong".  Perhaps the constraint could be enforced by the JavaFX system on a Desktop system, but it would be pretty hard to do so in an intuitive way because, usually, people don't expect enclosing windows to have a minimum size.  In mobile development the main stage is generally rendered full screen to the device.  This makes a constrained stage size based upon a scene root minimum size pretty hard to achieve, as the scene root is size is really governed by OS limitations and preferences, in addition to user actions such as resizing the main application window.